# Quartz - JobExecutionException for 'JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin_jobInitializer'

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I'm having what looks like a problem with Quartz 1.8.4. The 'problem' (which seems to have no effect on Quartz other than cluttering my log file) is displayed below.

Question: Why is this exception being thrown?

```
Jun 20, 2012 12:33:29 PM org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport storeTrigger
INFO: note: volatile triggers are effectively non-volatile in a clustered environment.
Jun 20, 2012 12:33:29 PM org.quartz.plugins.history.LoggingJobHistoryPlugin jobToBeExecuted
INFO: Job JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin.JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin_jobInitializer_quartz_jobs_xml fired (by trigger JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin.JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin_jobInitializer_quartz_jobs_xml) at:  12:33:29 06/20/2012
Jun 20, 2012 12:33:29 PM org.quartz.core.JobRunShell run
INFO: Job JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin.JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin_jobInitializer_quartz_jobs_xml threw a JobExecutionException: 
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: FileScanListener named 'JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin_jobInitializer' not found in SchedulerContext
    at org.quartz.jobs.FileScanJob.execute(FileScanJob.java:83)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
Jun 20, 2012 12:33:29 PM org.quartz.plugins.history.LoggingJobHistoryPlugin jobWasExecuted
WARNING: Job JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin.JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin_jobInitializer_quartz_jobs_xml execution failed at  12:33:29 06/20/2012 and reports: FileScanListener named 'JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin_jobInitializer' not found in SchedulerContext
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: FileScanListener named 'JobSchedulingDataLoaderPlugin_jobInitializer' not found in SchedulerContext
    at org.quartz.jobs.FileScanJob.execute(FileScanJob.java:83)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
```

quartz.properties file:

```
#============================================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = AcertJobScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AcertJobScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true

#============================================================================
# Configure ThreadPool  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true

#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000


#============================================================================
# Configure Datasources  
#============================================================================
<sanitized>

#============================================================================
# Configure Plugins 
#============================================================================
org.quartz.plugin.triggHistory.class = org.quartz.plugins.history.LoggingJobHistoryPlugin

org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class = org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames = quartz_jobs.xml
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = true
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval = 0
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.wrapInUserTransaction = false
```

quartz_jobs.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<job-scheduling-data xmlns="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_1_8.xsd"
  version="1.8">


<!-- SAP ACERT Synchronization Job-->
<schedule>
        <job>
            <name>AcertSapImport</name>
            <group>SapImport</group>

            <description>Synchronize the staff information from the HR SAP database
            to the ACERT users table; Locations, and org tree</description>
            <job-class>my.company.acert.sap_import.SapAcertSyncJob</job-class>
        </job>
        <trigger>
            <cron>
                <name>myTrigger</name>
                <group>SapImport</group>
                <job-name>AcertSapImport</job-name>
                <job-group>SapImport</job-group>
                <cron-expression>0 0 1 * * ?</cron-expression>
            </cron>
        </trigger>

        <job>
            <name>Nightly Course Maintenance</name>
            <group>Acert Maintenance</group>
            <description>Activates and deactivates courses and course versions based 
            on their started and end dates.</description>
            <job-class>my.company.acert.job.CourseMaintenanceJob</job-class>
        </job>
        <trigger>
            <cron>
                <name>courseTrigger</name>
                <group>Acert Maintenance</group>
                <job-name>Nightly Course Maintenance</job-name>
                <job-group>Acert Maintenance</job-group>
                <cron-expression>0 0 2 * * ?</cron-expression>
            </cron>
        </trigger>
        <job>
            <name>Historic Backup</name>
            <group>Acert Maintenance</group>
            <description>Runs the stored procedure to take a snapshot of acert at this date.</description>
            <job-class>my.company.acert.job.HistoricBackupJob</job-class>
        </job>
        <trigger>
            <cron>
                <name>historicBackupTrigger</name>
                <group>Acert Maintenance</group>
                <job-name>Historic Backup</job-name>
                <job-group>Acert Maintenance</job-group>
                <cron-expression>0 0 3 1 * ?</cron-expression>
            </cron>
        </trigger>
        <job>
            <name>Parse XMLs for OrgUnit Trees</name>
            <group>Org Tree</group>

            <description>Parses the xml files for the org tree and reporting org tree</description>
            <job-class>my.company.acert.sap_import.ParseTreeXMLJob</job-class>
        </job>
        <trigger>
            <cron>
                <name>parseOrgTreeTrigger</name>
                <group>Org Tree</group>
                <job-name>Parse XMLs for OrgUnit Trees</job-name>
                <job-group>Org Tree</job-group>
                <cron-expression>0 0 2 1 * ?</cron-expression>
            </cron>
        </trigger>
        <job>
            <name>Notify Expiry Courses</name>
            <group>Notifications</group>

            <description>Send email notification to supervisor and learners of current and upcoming course expirations.</description>
            <job-class>my.company.acert.job.NotifyCourseExpiryJob</job-class>
        </job>
        <trigger>
            <cron>
                <name>notifyExpiryCoursesTrigger</name>
                <group>Notifications</group>
                <job-name>Notify Expiry Courses</job-name>
                <job-group>Notifications</job-group>
                <cron-expression>0 0 3 * * ?</cron-expression>
            </cron>
        </trigger>

</schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

I am running this on Tomcat 7.0.27.

Comment: It seems like the scheduler was not able to locate the quartz_jobs.xml file and hence could not build up the context for that. However, you said jobs from .xml are being executed and that makes to wonder how. Either there's an issue with Quartz itself or in your configuration. So just narrow down the scenario by running it on latest version of Quartz.

Comment: have you tried with a scanInterval of 10? does it still have the same warning? my guess is that it's not able to obtain a lock on the file

Answer (score 0):

I debugged the code and found that ,this exception occurs when listener name is not found in the scheduler context. In simple words, please see if the class files which you want to invoke are present at classpath and their path is correctly setup in property file. A simple spell mistake may cause this exception. An easy way is to schedule only one instance first to see if it's working without warning, then add another and see for warning and so on.

```
  FileScanListener listener = (FileScanListener)schedCtxt.get(listenerName);

  if(listener == null) {
        throw new JobExecutionException("FileScanListener named '" + 
                    listenerName + "' not found in SchedulerContext");
  }
```

Hope it helps.